# React rendering pdf from S3 with content-type multipart or binary/octect-steam

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a pdf in my react app, but the content type I am getting is not `application/pdf`. Hence it is getting downloaded instead of getting rendered. I have tried downloading it first and then loading it as a blob object but no success there.
More info will be provided when asked as I am not sure what more should be added here.

Comment: What do you use to render your PDF? And what went wrong when loading it as a blob?

Comment: I used embed, iframe, react-pdf to render and while while using the blob object, I am able to render in a new browser tab. I want to render it in the same page.

Comment: Does react-pdf return any error?